# How to connect to SocialBakers API with R

Tags: r, shiny, connection

I need to develop a Shiny App using the server available from shinyapps.io that connects to data from a SocialBakers account. I looked at the documentation in 
https://api.socialbakers.com/#introduction, and in fact there is information to connect to their API but I don't understand how to make it work on Shiny (or R for that matter).

I managed to connect with data from a Google Analytics account, but only because of the existence of an R package to do just that: `googleAnalyticsR`

How would you do this? I would appreciate help to know at least where to start.

Comment: you should consider the 'httr' package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/index.html

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/api-packages.html / https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2017/06/interfacing-with-apis.html / https://tophcito.blogspot.com/2015/11/accessing-apis-from-r-and-little-r.html / https://tclavelle.github.io/blog/r_and_apis/ / https://www.programmableweb.com/news/how-to-access-any-restful-api-using-r-language/how-to/2017/07/21 / https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=usXZNnc0JK4